# .htacces file doesnt work for me, clean url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to adress to my website to look like this `localhost/articles, localhost/news`

but even if I use .htacces file, adresses to my site look like this `localhost/index.php?page=articles`

My .htacces file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

Does anyone know where the problem is? Thank you!

Comment: Have you changed the links? (i.e. the `<a>`).

Comment: Try accessing the domain you want to work.

Comment: Unclear: Are you using `localhost/articles` but the browser is being _redirected_ to `localhost/index.php?page=articles` when you don't want the address to change? What happens specifically when you enter `localhost/articles`?

Comment: Also unclear: Simply creating the rewrite will not force your site to use the rewritten address. That requires additional work.

Comment: The file name should be `.htaccess`

Comment: When I enter localhost/articles it says that this page doesnt exist

Comment: Is the `.htaccess` file named right? (On here, you are missing out the last `s`).

Comment: First mistake was filename as Mike W said. But now if I want to acces my site, it says this - The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled on the server?

Comment: Yes, I got it! Thank you! First problem was with the name of the file and second was that mod_rewrite was disabled. Now it works! Thank you all for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server may be running apache with `mod_rewrite` disabled (I get the same error when I disable it).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?page=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

Additionally, all of your links need to look like:

```
<a href="/articles">
```

instead of:

```
<a href="/index.php?page=articles">
```